# WPF left button, centered text, right button in a custom control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to prototype a new custom control that has a left button, text, and right button.

The XAML looks like this:

```
<StackPanel Width="250" Orientation="Vertical" >
 
    <DockPanel Background="Azure" Width="250">
        <Button Name="btnLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30" Background="DarkGray" Click="btnAdd_Click" Template="{DynamicResource StandardButtonTemplate1}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/Previous25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="imgLeft"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

        <TextBlock Name="tblkModelType" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20">Import</TextBlock>
        
        <Button Name="btnRight"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30" Background="DarkGray"  Click="btnAdd_Click" Template="{DynamicResource StandardButtonTemplate1}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/Next25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="imgRight"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The buttons are left and right justified ok, but the  (tblkModelType) is left justified right up next to the left button.  It doesn't appear that HorizontalAlignment on that tag does anything.  If I remove the right button, the TextBlock does center.

Anyone know how to get the buttons on the outside and the TextBlock centered in the Dockpanel?  I guess I could use a grid, but it would make the rest of the control more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<DockPanel Background="Azure" Width="250" >
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="btnLeft" Width="30" Background="DarkGray" Click="btnAdd_Click" Template="{DynamicResource StandardButtonTemplate1}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/Images/Previous25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="imgLeft"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>           

    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Name="btnRight" Width="30" Background="DarkGray"  Click="btnAdd_Click" Template="{DynamicResource StandardButtonTemplate1}" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/Images/Next25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="imgRight"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="tblkModelType" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20">Import</TextBlock>
</DockPanel>
```

Use `DockPanel.Dock` to dock `btnLeft` to the left of the `DockPanel`, `btnRight` to the right. Then for `tblkModelType` set `DockPanel.Dock="Top"`. This will stretch the `TextBlock` to the entire width of the `DockPanel` between buttons.

This works for me. As you said your control is more complex, so in case of any problem share more xaml with us.

Comment: This kind of works...  The text does go to the center, but the DockPanel is expanded vertically and the right button is shifted down.  I added in the rest of the XAML (it's just a enclosing StackPanel)

Comment: NEVER MIND! I had to change the order and put the TextBlock at the end...  Crazy! Thank you!